# Efficient design for multiple pixel operations when decompressing an image

Tags: c++, templates, graphics, pixel

I maintain an image codec that requires post processing of the image with a varying number of simple pixel operations: for example, gain, colour transform, scaling, truncating.  Some ops work on single channels, while others (colour transform) work on three channels at a time.

When an image is decoded, it is stored in planar format, one buffer per channel.

I want to design an efficient framework in c++ that can apply a specified series of pixel ops. Since this is the inner loop, I need it to be efficient - pixel ops should be inlined, with minimum branching.

Simplest approach is to have a fixed array of say 20 operands, and pass this array with the actual number of ops to the post-process method. Can someone suggest a more clever way ?

Edit: This would be a block operation, for efficiency, and I do plan on using SIMD to accelerate. So, for each pixel, I want to efficiently perform a configurable sequence of pixel ops, using SIMD instructions.

Comment: I think your question is a bit unclear. What's the goal of the framework? A nice API? What's the problem of your suggested approach? Why do you need to inject the operations into the post-prcess functions, why not just write a single loop? Perhaps add a small example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Generally, I suupse you might want to look into expression templates.

Comment: If you're looking for simple efficiency, it's likely that performing one operation at a time (over an entire image, block or scanline) will result in faster code due to vectorizable operations.  If you suddenly switch to a pipeline of operations for every pixel, chances are that you'll not only lose these kinds of optimizations, but create an even less optimal situation due to a chain of references.

Comment: This is generally true, but depending on the algorithm it can be beneficial to run the whole processing chain block wise (size depends on the available SIMD instruction set) in order to improve cache efficiency. But especially for images where you may have spacial dependencies distributed across the whole data this may not work.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend to execute the pipeline at the pixel level, this will be horribly inefficient (and inapplicable for some operations), do it for whole images.

As you suggested, it is an easy matter to encode the sequence of operations and associated arguments as a list, and write a simple execution engine that will call the desired functions.

Probably some of your operations are done in-place and some other require an extra buffer. You will need to add suitable buffer management. Nothing
insurmountable.

Comment: Thanks. The key issue for me is how to manage a configurable sequence of low level ops in an efficient manner. I would rather to block operations rather than single op per frame, as I want to use the cache efficiently.

Comment: @Jacko: executing the processing chain at the pixel level will be a disaster (except maybe by compiling the sequence - even that is dubious).